# Compare two decimals and print similarities in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a script that compares two very similar decimal numbers and I want the script to print the portion that the two numbers share. For example, suppose I have the numbers 42.86579 and 42.84578. Since both numbers have the 42.8 portion in common, I would like the script to output 42.8. How should I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search for the longest common prefix in two strings with `sed`:

```
$ x=42.86579
$ y=42.84578    
$ sed "s/\(.*\).* \1.*/\1/" <<< "$x $y"
42.8
```

Or slightly more concisely using GNU grep:

```
$ grep -Po '(.*).* \K\1' <<< "$x $y"
42.8
```

Comment: Back reference, nice idea! This is possible too with GNU grep: `grep -Po '(.*).* \K\1' <<< "$x $y"`

Comment: Another variant with sed: `sed "s/\(.*\).* \1.*/\1/" <<< "$x $y"`

Comment: @Cyrus: Cool. I've updated the answer. The `grep` version is still the most compact :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a=42.86579
b=42.84578

[[ ${a%.*} !=  ${b%.*} ]] && exit
for ((i=0;i<${#a};i++)); do 
  if [[ ${a:$i:1} == ${b:$i:1} ]]; then 
    echo -n ${a:$i:1}
  else
    break
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
42.8
```

---

See: [Bash's parameter expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32)